# Julia Plots Package does not download and crashes julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, ijulia-notebook, julia-plots

I recently got Julia for my Scientific Computation class and downloaded packages. Majority of the packages downloaded perfectly without issue but when I go to download the Plots Package it gives this error. "`Unitful=1986cc42-f94f-5a68-af5c-568840ba703d` depends on `InverseFunctions=3587e190-3f89-42d0-90ee-14403ec27112`, but no such entry exists in the manifest." I have tried deleting and re-downloading VSCode, Julia and the Julia extension but nothing seems to resolve it. If needed I can send the manifest.toml file.

I have tried deleting and re-downloading and also deleting the manifest and project file and then running the instantiating common in the terminal.

Comment: how did you install julia?

Comment: try to delete ~/.julia  folder  (or .julia in your home folder) and reinstall packages - the package repo might be corrupt.

Comment: I downloaded Julia from the Julia Download website and clicked on the windows x64 Installer

Comment: Deleting the .julia file and redownloading the packages seems to have worked. Thanks a log Przemysalw Szufel